# collect RDD output as a stream

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, output

I have a job that end like this

```
val iteratorRDD: RDD[Iterator[SomeClass]] = ....

val results = iteratorRDD.map( iterator => iterator.toSeq)
                         .collect
```

The iterators are lazy, i.e. they compute the data when their items are accessed, here the `toSeq` which would basically call `.next()` iteratively.

Now, this computation is slow and I want to get the output of the iterator as soon as they are generated, basically at each `iterator.next()`. The reason is that the later steps (run locally) are processing the items in order: `f(all the first items)`, then `f(all the seconds)`, etc... and I need to get these a soon as possible, thus before the end of the job.

Does spark provide some mean to retrieve intermediate results as some kind of stream? Or maybe there exist a distributed data structure to which the iterator could send the intermediate data?

What I could do is the setup a web-service that would act as such a buffer: it would listen for data that would be send by each call to iterator.next().  Then have my main program call that web-service to get what it stores. But I don't like the idea of having all the worker communicating to an external service.

Answer (score 0):

I would not make any sense to do so. An iterator if fine for traversal when you don't want to create copies in local memory, but Spark works differently. Your iterators are distributed across multiple executors (in separate nodes, with separate memory), so when you call collect you will force them to be iterated and sent to the master anyway, where they will be loaded into memory. There is simply no way you can do lazy evaluation from the master to data that lives in the executors.

You should strive to send the computation to the data and not the other way around, especially if you are going to be running the same code on each sequence anyway! For instance:

```
val results = iteratorRDD
  .map(iter => f(iter)) // Whatever f() returns.
  .collect()
```

You then evaluate your iterator lazily and in parallel, on the executors, only bringing the actual results to the master.

Comment: I did not speak about input data, so consider it is in the iterator: `val inputData = sc.textFile(hdfs_url) ; iteratorRdd = inputData.map( line => makeIterator(line)` Thus the iterator is the computation wrapped around the data. Now my point is that it compute (lazily) a sequence of values, on each worker. And I'd like to receive the first before all are computed.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. So let me rephrase the question: why do you have to receive these on the master at all? Why collect them to run the "later step"?

Comment: The later steps cannot be run on public cloud (or else I find a way to hide sensible information, but that's quite hard) also, the output size is not that big.

Comment: Then I'm afraid there is no `.collectIterator()` function that does what you want, and given how Spark works, they might never be.